# how to get the remote url

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using

> `Dim url As String = Server.MapPath("MyFiles") & "\" &
>   System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName)`

to get the url of the uploaded file.

The result i get is

> D:\2008VS\LTC INDIA\LTCIndia v 1.52\AdminPanel\MyFiles\1.jpg

i want it to be like this  `http://www.abcd.com/AdminPanel/MyFiles/1.jpg`

Kindly let me know if posting the whole code would be of any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [ResolveUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx) method:

```
Dim url As String = ResolveUrl("~/MyFiles/" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName))
```